# How do I implement a 'Look at' function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, rotation, position

I have two 4x4 homogeneous transform frames, A and T.

A is moving with time and T is stationary. I'm trying to create a function that rotates T such that it is always looking at A but doesnt move its position. Similarly to the LookAt function in OpenGL and Unity

If A moves from point [0,0,0] to [1,2,-1], how do i generate a rotation matrix that when multiplied with T, the new frame is T rotated to face A.

[Problem Visualised](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LotKF.jpg)

**My Attempt** (feel free to ignore if you know a better method)

I tried calculating the distance between the positions (not orientation) of A and T two times, first for when A is still at the origin and then secondly for when A has moved, (This position is B).

I then took the cross product of these two distance vectors to get a vector perpendicular to both these vectors that will act as the axis of rotation.

I then used the cosine rule to find the angle of which to rotate about said axis. The sides used where the lengths from AB, TB, TA (Where B is the position A moved to).

Finally i used rodrigues formula of rotation plugging in the axis and angle. The result is somewhat correct however it only works for when A is moved in the direction of X and Z axis for some reason.

MATLAB code:

```
         TA = (T.POSITION - A.POSITION);       % Vectors
         TB = (T.POSITION - B.POSITION);   
         AB = (A.POSITION - B.POSITION);

         RotationAngle = acos( (TA^2 + TB^2 - AB^2)/(2*TA*TB))
         RotationAxis = cross(TA,TB)
         RotationAxis_Normalized = RotationAxis/norm(RotationAxis);

          AxisTemp = VecToso3(RotationAxis_Normalized);
          RotMat= eye(3,3) + (sin(RotationAngle)*AxisTemp) + ((1-cos(RotationAngle))*(AxisTemp^2));      % Rodrigues rotation

          updated_target_config =  T.TRANSFORM * CreateTransform(RotMat); % Multiply T by the rotation matrix so it looks at B
```

Is there a better way to do this?